# Can an object be moved through a match expression?

Tags: rust

I am using Rust 1.15.1 and, recently, I stumbled over a problem I could not find a straight forward solution for.

When you look at examples using pattern matching they usually destructure the object in the match expression and continue to work with members within that object. However, I'd like to NOT destructure it, but only match against it and dispatch the complete object (using move semantics) to one of several other functions depending on its properties.

The following code works and does exactly what I need. However, I need to introduce an "artificial" enum type and a second match expression. I wonder if there is a more straight forward and simpler solution?

```
#[derive(Debug)]
enum Number {
    Constant { value: i32 },
}

fn process_even(n: Number) {
    println!("even: {:?}", n);
}

fn process_odd(n: Number) {
    println!("odd: {:?}", n);
}

fn process(n: Number) {
    enum Action {
        ProcessEven,
        ProcessOdd,
    }

    let action = match n {
        Number::Constant { value: c, .. } if 0 == c % 2 => Action::ProcessEven,
        _ => Action::ProcessOdd,
    };

    match action {
        Action::ProcessEven => process_even(n),
        Action::ProcessOdd => process_odd(n),
    }
}

fn main() {
    process(Number::Constant { value: 4711 });
    process(Number::Constant { value: 2000 });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try just *using* `n`?

```
fn process(n: Number) {
    match n {
        Number::Constant { value: c, .. } if c % 2 == 0 => process_even(n),
        _ => process_odd(n)
    }
}
```

That works because `value` is `i32`, which is `Copy`, which means the compiler can copy it out, without needing to move or borrow it.  If you're dealing with more complicated types than that, you might not be able to avoid the second stage.

That said, even in *that* case, if you've only got two options, you could return `true` or `false`.  *Or* you could return `process_even`/`process_odd` directly as function pointers from the first match and call that:

```
fn process(n: Number) {
    let action = match n {
        Number::Constant { value: c, .. } if c % 2 == 0 => process_even as fn(_),
        _ => process_odd
    };

    action(n)
}
```

Comment: You are right! I simplified the code too much. I should have used something which is NOT `Copy`as value. What you suggested is exactly what I had in mind and actually tired to do. However, as you already mentioned, this seems to only work with members that implement `Copy` trait. Using a 'bool' works in the special case of two alternatives, but one would make use of the same mechanism. Using function pointers might be the simple solution I am looking for. I'll try, thanks :-)

Comment: @JonnyDee I added an example of using a function pointer.